# Bookmarklet to remove text in the first part of a URL

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarklet

I'm looking for a bookmarklet that will modify the current URL to remove any text before the last HTTP. For example:

1. Take the current page:  https://web.archive.org/web/20180922081247/http://www.falseknees.com/335.html
2. and change it to http://www.falseknees.com/335.html
3. then load the new URL

I tried searching for a bookmarklet that can do this, but no luck. There are a lot of bookmarklets to go to the Archive.org record of a page, but not the reverse.

Extra points if anyone can provide a bookmarklet that can convert all links on the site-map page from Archive.org to deeplink directly to the live page:

1. Take this page: https://web.archive.org/web/sitemap/http://falseknees.com/
2. Convert all links on the page to deeplink directly to the original site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow! 
Here's a simple bookmarklet for the first part of your question:

```
javascript:window.location = location.href.substring(location.href.lastIndexOf('http'));
```

Caveat: it won't work correctly if 'http' appears anywhere else in the archive.org link.

The second part of your question is a little more involved. You might want to split out the 'bonus' portion into a new question to get quicker answers.

Comment: Works great! Thanks